# Button containing images with different dimensions for down and up states

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button where the down and up states are pretty different - the dimensions of the two images differ and one way to make it is to detect touch events and replace the two images as necessary. 
My current idea for resolving this is with a FrameLayout like below and using it multiple times:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSettingDown"
        android:src="@drawable/button_settings_down"
        android:layout_marginTop="647dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="425dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSetting"
        android:src="@drawable/button_settings"
        android:layout_marginTop="657dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="432dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

But is it possible to define it as a template or something?
I have more than one button like this and it would be better if this could be made like a custom xml that can have custom attributes and to be more easily reused in other applications too. I need to be able to set src, layout_marginTop and layout_marginLeft for each image of each button.

I am open to other proposals to handle the issue, but making the down and up states the same dimensions is not an option.

Comment: Your current idea is wrong. You should use a selector (state list drawable): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: @Der Golem Selector would be good choice if the dimensions of the two images are the same. But in my case the two images have different positions on the screen. If they were with the same dimensions, they could have been placed on the same position (at least in my case) and I could have just used selectors.